# Eclipse ADT won't run/install app on to my Device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, installation, adb

I'm trying to run my App from Eclipse with ADT in to my device Asus 450CG with 5.0 Lollipop..

the ADT is recognize my Device, as I activate Debug on my device, and the drivers for device has already installed. and when I click O.K to run on my device, there is no error it says

upload MeetApplication.apk...

Install Meet Application.apk on to device...

Success...

Start Activity com.pjb.meetapps2.splashscreen ..

but after that it is still nothing happend on my phone..
there's no MeetApplication installed on my phone..

what happend ??
any Ideas,, ??

Comment: look into the log, any message ??? try to restart adb also once...

Comment: does catlog give you a hint? Is your device's screen locked ?

Comment: Check Manifest file , in the activity section a default "<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />" should be there in the intent filter of your launcher activity TAG.

Comment: the manifest file is fine

Comment: there's nothing on CatLog...  only this in Android DDMS Section [2015-06-30 14:51:18 - MeetAppliation] ------------------------------
[2015-06-30 14:51:18 - MeetAppliation] Android Launch!
[2015-06-30 14:51:18 - MeetAppliation] adb is running normally.
[2015-06-30 14:51:18 - MeetAppliation] Performing com.pjb.meetapps2.SplashScreen activity launch
[2015-06-30 14:51:25 - MeetAppliation] Uploading MeetAppliation.apk onto device 'E9AZCY025825'
[2015-06-30 14:51:26 - MeetAppliation] Installing MeetAppliation.apk...
[2015-06-30 14:51:27 - MeetAppliation] Success!